# aws Push from django python causes my server database to be replaced by local database

Tags: python, django, git, amazon-web-services, git-push

After Making a few changes on the code, when i push the entire project using -

```
git add .
git commit -m "push"
aws push
```

From my local virtual connection to the aws, my server database is replaced by the local database.

How can i avoid this?

I am using Models to store data in Django.